# How to notify client that list has been modified

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I need answer for following question, suppose the application is ASP.NET application or WPF application.

you have two screens live on two different machines one having an employee list and one having add employee screen what can be done when  employee gets added the screen displaying the employee list gets a message that an employee has been added.

Please advise,

Comment: You can have a backgound thread which always look for updated and notify

Comment: Or you can update a common data store, i.e., a shared database, that both windows can monitor periodically (perhaps with background threads).

Comment: Need to suppose one or the other.   Does that employee get added to a server?

Comment: Yes, it will get added to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WCF service to mediate between clients. When employee gets added first client send information to service. Then WCF service send callback to second client. See [WCF callbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx)

Comment: This can be easily achieved by implementing Signalr as well

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET server can't notify client about changes. You have to use some external library like SignalR (http://signalr.net/) to force client to remain in connection with server permanently and to make a possibility to notify clients about changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an **ObservableCollection** you can listen to the **CollectionChanged** event and check the arguments as to whether an item has been added.